# Is it possible to use an Exchange user group to authenticate users on a ColdFusion app?

Tags: coldfusion, exchange-server, coldfusion-9

The only tags I've found are these [cfexchangecalendar](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_12.html), [cfexchangeconnection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_13.html), [cfexchangecontact](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_14.html), [cfexchangefilter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_15.html), [cfexchangemail](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_16.html), and [cfexchangetask](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_17.html). I don't think I can accomplish what I want with these tags. Does anyone know if or how this can be done?

Comment: do you have access to Active Directory as well? If you do you can use the `cfldap` tags.

Comment: CFexchangecontact would the closest. It pulls user information, but I don't think security is in there